# MacBook Pro 2015 does not output video via HDMI or MiniDisplay port

Tags: macbook-pro, video, hdmi, displayport, television

#### Problem

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro. I also have a JVC television with an HDMI port. When I connect the two via an HDMI cable, the laptop appears to recognize that I've connected to another display (the television shows up in System Preferences). Unfortunately the picture on the television is blank, as if it's not receiving a video signal at all.

I've tried connecting via the MiniDisplay port (and a MD to HDMI converter) and the results are identical. I've also found that I can connect a 2010 MacBook Air to the television without issue.

#### Things I've tried

I've restarted the machine, reset the SMC, and turned the television off and on several times.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the MBA work with the same cables? does the MBP output video to different screens?

Comment: Yes, the MBA works with the MiniDisplay port cable. The MBP does output to another monitor without issue. This would make me think that the problem is the television but it doesn't seem to have issue with the MBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The television appears to be unable to handle higher resolutions. Here's what ended up working:

1. Change the resolution for the television to "Scaled" via System Preferences.
2. Tick checkbox for "Show all resolutions"
3. Select 480p. At this point the image shows up on the television.
4. Now I can change the setting to 720p and the television updates accordingly.

Unfortunately the television is unable to handle anything higher than 720p.